# Joining tables with multiple columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm having an issue when trying to join two tables though. It is Google Analytics data. In my first table I have google ads data, split by the dimensions **campaign_id** and **date**, then I have some metrics (impressions, clicks, and cost).

Something like:

| Date | Campaign_ID | Clicks | Impressions | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-08-01 | 13345 | 345 | 10,045 | 296 |
| 2019-08-02 | 12343 | 452 | 23,033 | 359 |
| 2019-08-03 | 132456 | 587 | 25,056 | 562 |

So far so good for my knowledge. I then have a 2nd table which has transactions in it, the transactions are individual transactions with the transaction ID so needs to be in a separate table. I have again the dimensions **date** and **campaign_ID**, plus **transaction id**. And metric of revenue. I'm not actually bothered about revenue, its just in my table but can be ingnored.

So 2nd table is:

| Date | Campaign_ID | Transaction_ID | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-08-01 | 12343 | A1100 | 5000 |
| 2019-08-01 | 12343 | A1101 | 5000 |

What I'm trying to do with the data is count the number of transactions by date and campaign_ID and then join this to table 1 by date and campaign_ID.

My query to count the transactions is very straightforward:

```
SELECT 
date,
campaign_ID
count(Transaction_ID) as transactions

From bqproject.tables.ga_ecom_data
GROUP BY Date, Campaign_ID
```

This gives exactly the data I need, and I can use a join with a seperate table to join the 1st table and the query above.

What I'm trying to achieve though is to put this in a single query so that I can pull the impressions, clicks and cost data, then count the transactions, and join them together by date and campaign_ID.

Hopefully that makes sense in terms of my query.

I was trying to use select (select  but the error I've getting back states that nesting queries using select can only return a single column where as I'm trying to return 3. I've tried using select struct but I can't figure out the correct format, or if it is right.

So I've gone with another route (based on some youtube videos I've been following), the query here doesn't break, but I don't get my column "count_transaction_ID".

Here is the query I've used:

```
SELECT newdate,
 CID,
  AD_I,
   Ad_Click,
    AD_COST ,


    FROM (SELECT Date as newdate, Campaign_ID as CID, SUM(Ad_Impressions) as AD_I, SUM(Ad_Clicks) as AD_Click, SUM(Ad_Cost) as AD_COST
    from `bqproject.tables.ga_ads_data`
    GROUP BY Date, Campaign_ID) A
    JOIN
     (
SELECT Date, Campaign_ID, COUNT(Transaction_ID)
FROM `bqproject.tables.ga_ecom_data`
group by Date, Campaign_ID

    ) B 
    ON A.newdate = B.Date
    AND A.CID = B.Campaign_ID

    LIMIT 1000
```

What I was trying to get back is a table such as:

| Date | Campaign_ID | Clicks | Impressions | Cost | Count_Of_Transactions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-08-01 | 13345 | 345 | 10,045 | 296 | 5 |
| 2019-08-02 | 12343 | 452 | 23,033 | 359 | 16 |
| 2019-08-03 | 132456 | 587 | 25,056 | 562 | 10 |

But the table data which is returned doesn't show the count(transactions).

I don't know if I'm using the wrong structure here and should be using different subqueries, or if this isn't actually possibly to do. It feels like it should be, but it's just past my understanding at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the columns required for display in the first table then join second table using count to roll up the transactions, something like:

```
SELECT 
first.Campaign_ID, 
first.Date,
first.Impressions,
first.Clicks,
first.Cost,
count(second.Transaction_ID) transactions
from `bqproject.tables.ga_ads_data` first
left join `bqproject.tables.ga_ecom_data` second
on first.Campaign_ID = second.Campaign_ID and first.Date = second.Date
group by 
first.Campaign_ID,
first.Date,
first.Ad_Impressions,
first.Ad_clicks,
first.Ad_cost
order by first.Campaign_ID, first.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

you are pretty close!

```
SELECT A.newdate,
       A.CID,
       A.AD_I,
       A.Ad_Click,
       A.AD_COST,
       B.transactions
FROM (SELECT Date                as newdate,
             Campaign_ID         as CID,
             SUM(Ad_Clicks)      as AD_Click,
             SUM(Ad_Cost)        as AD_COST,
             SUM(Ad_Impressions) as AD_I,
      from `bqproject.tables.ga_ads_data`
      GROUP BY Date, Campaign_ID
     ) A
         left JOIN
     (
         SELECT Date, Campaign_ID, COUNT(distinct Transaction_ID) as transactions
         FROM `bqproject.tables.ga_ecom_data`
         group by Date, Campaign_ID
     ) B
     ON A.newdate = B.Date
         AND A.CID = B.Campaign_ID
```

Let me know if this helps! Naming helps a lot when using subqueries, you just needed to add B.transactions to the primary select statement.

PD1: Just a tip going forward, try to keep column names as consistent as possible and also try to avoid capitalization! It will help your development timeline.

PD2: Watch out using simple join, that kind of join will not select campaigns without transactionIds.

Comment: Absolutely amazing thanks, that has really helped with the additional comments too. I added the naming, and then checked the data and realised it was the numbers were out slgihtly. I used left join and it seems to have sorted it nicely! I need to understand the join left more but the numbers are perfect. thanks again!

Comment: FYI, I was also going down the route below after I posted my question. It's not giving me the right number of impressions, but the trans count works. But it really helped me to undersand the naming too. thanks again.      SELECT 
pss_data.Date,
SUM(pss_data.Ad_Impressions) as Impressions,
Count(ecom_data.Transaction_ID) as trans
From `data-studio-tables.tables.pss_ga_data_initial_pull` pss_data
LEFT JOIN `data-studio-tables.tables.pss_ecom_initial_pull` ecom_data

ON (pss_data.Date = ecom_data.Date
AND pss_data.Campaign_ID = ecom_data.Campaign_ID)
GROUP BY pss_data.Date

LIMIT 1000

Comment: @MarkPitchford I'd check 2 things: (1) Check if Clicks, Impressions are Costs are accumulative per day -> In case they are, the sum doesn't mean anything and you'd have to catch the newest value. (2) Maybe you can try using count(distinct ecom_data.Transaction_Id) -> that way you count all distinct Ids and make sure you are not repeating

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to name the count column and then add it to the above call. See below:

```
SELECT newdate,
 CID,
  AD_I,
   Ad_Click,
    AD_COST , b.counttransactions

    FROM (SELECT Date as newdate, Campaign_ID as CID, SUM(Ad_Impressions) as AD_I, SUM(Ad_Clicks) as AD_Click, SUM(Ad_Cost) as AD_COST
    from `bqproject.tables.ga_ads_data`
    GROUP BY Date, Campaign_ID) A
    JOIN
     (
SELECT Date, Campaign_ID, COUNT(Transaction_ID) as countTransactions
FROM `bqproject.tables.ga_ecom_data`
group by Date, Campaign_ID

    ) B 
    ON A.newdate = B.Date
    AND A.CID = B.Campaign_ID

    LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: amazing thank you! Just mentioned in the comment below but I used your answer first, then realised needed to use left join. Really helped me out though. Really appreciate it